# FlyoutNavigation sub viewcontroller can't perform segue on main controller?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, segue, xamarin

Using flyout navigation on monotouch by James Clancey.  Can't get a subview controller to elegantly perform a segue on the main containing controller?

```
        NavigationRoot = new RootElement ("Navigation") {
            new Section ("Menu") {
                new StringElement ("Mapview Controller"),
                new StringElement ("Another View Controller"),
            }
        },

        ViewControllers = new [] {

      // mapview is a view inside this viewcontroller and able to perform segues
            new UIViewController { View = mapView },

      // this is a seperate viewcontroller but is embedded inside the flyoutNavigation
     // AnotherViewController cant seem to call the root navigation controller (<-- actually a uiNav inside a tab bar nav) so i can perform a segue movement just like the above mapViewController??
            this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AnotherViewController") as AnotherViewController,

        },


    // sub viewcontroller i.e. AnotherViewController trying to move mainViewController to perform a segue..
    // throws error: Receiver (<FlyoutNavigation.FlyoutNavigationController: 0x14360600>) has no segue with identifier 'segueTest'

   this.ParentViewController.PerformSegue("segueTest", this);
```

*** Update:
I gave up on segue.  Instead of using additional view controllers, I'm relying on views but one of my views is a static-celled tableview and not sure how to add it to above code liek so:

```
        ViewControllers = new [] {
            new UIViewController { View = mapView },
            new UIViewController { View = myTableView } // doesnt work - tried with 'new UITableViewController' which also fails
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use navigation for that..

```
  ViewControllers = new [] {

new UINavigationController (this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("profileViewController") as ProfileViewController),
}
```

Comment: How do you get Storyboard instance in AppDelegate class? I am having a similar problem and I am using the FlyoutNavigationController as the root and hence need to instantiate the controllers in AppDelegate and they are using Storyboard